# I have an Arduino Yun and when i use putty (SSH) to execute mkdir command it shows "can't create directory: No such file or directory"

Tags: linux

The web page related to this is [Link](https://learn.adafruit.com/smart-measuring-cup/arduino-yun-setup)

I connected Yun with my laptop and use root to run the putty

I'm trying to use mkdir but it shows

```
root@spare:~# mkdir /mnt/sda1/python-packages
mkdir: can't create directory '/mnt/sda1/python-packages': No such file or  directory
```

need help on this

I tried to creat a folder in the SD card named "python-packages" but it didn't work

Comment: mkdir is a Linux command; might be appropriate to add a Linux tag.

Comment: This question has nothing to do with python or putty -- you could reproduce it without either. Doesn't really have anything to do with SSH either, nor are the tools or the error specific to the Arduino distro in question in such a way that familiarity with it is helpful to diagnose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like one of those directories doesn't exist.  Maybe you didn't mount sda1.  You could also try the -p switch to create parent directories, and see what happens...

```
mkdir -p /mnt/sda1/python-packages
```

Comment: @GuDi, mkdir is not **supposed** to have output: When it's silent you know it succeeded.

Comment: You might want to check whether the folder was actually created on the memory card, or whatever is supposed to be mounted at sda1...